# How to produce really poor network quality and low GPS signal strength in Android Studio emulator?

Tags: android, user-interface, networking, cellular-network

***Description of the problem:***

I have an application that uses Firebase (authentication service, firestore and firebase storage, crashlitycs, etc...). In functions where internet access is required, for example when logging in the user, I use this method to determine if there is internet connection:

```
fun isNetworkAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
            val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            val activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
            return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected
}
```

In Android Studio everything is working fine. But when the user with a real device goes to an area where the network is usually off and GPS signal strength is low (in a forest for example), the app keeps freezing and crashing with various exceptions. The problem even occurs during activites where no internet is needed at all (like taking a picture, browsing a directory). How could I reproduce this in an Android Studio emulator?

***What I have tried so far:***

- I've tried setting high latency (10-20s) and low speed (1-2kB/s) for emulator with `-netdelay` and `-netspeed` switches when
  starting from console.
- I've tried playing with the cellular options of the emulator.

None of the methods above could reproduce the freezing screens that users face in forests or mountains. Without the ability to debug, I have not been able to find out what freezes the UI thread. Any ideas what could I do?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the freezing/crashing is GPS related rather than network related. What worked for me is driving around until I found a parking garage nearby that had no GPS signal.

Also, you should absolutely add Firebase Crashlytics so that you can get crash reports when these events happen.

Comment: I have removed the implementation of LocationListener from the app, but the problem still occured. That was the only place where I used GPS. Is it possible that firebase is trying to obtain some location data in the background, and somehow this leads to UI freeze/crash?

Comment: It's impossible to say without any crash reporting or without having the entire code base to look through.